# C++ - Does passing by reference utilize implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I am trying to get a better understanding of what "passing by reference" really does in c++. In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int& refVar) {
    std::cout << refVar;
}

int main() {
    int val = 3;
    func(val);
}
```

How does `func` taking in a reference change the behavior of `val` when `func` is called? Is the `val` variable implicitly converted to a "reference" type and then passed into the function, just like how `val` would be converted to a `float` if `func` took in a `float` instead of an `int`? Or is it something else?

Similarly, in this code:

```
int val = 3;
int& ref = val;
```

How is a reference of `val` assigned to `ref`? Is there implicit type conversion that can be also achieved manually using a function, or does the compiler realize without converting that `ref` is a reference and that it needs to store the address of `val`?

Comment: You're asking about implementation details.  The compiler could generate an assembly label for val like `val: dw 0x3`, and then when it comes across the reference, `ref:` just before `val: dw 0x3` so they are the exact same thing with just different labels.

Comment: Are you familiar with pointers, and how they work?

Comment: The compiler is under no obligation to use pointers or even make a function call in this case. The function and value can be inlined, and the result would basically be `int main() { std::cout << 3; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just try it?

https://godbolt.org/z/8or3qfd5G

Note that the compiler could do implicit conversion and pass a reference to the temporary.

But the only (good) reason to request a reference is to either store the reference for later use or modify the value. The former would produce a dangling reference and the later would modify a value that will be deleted when the function returns and can never be accessed. So effectively this construct is just bad.

The C++ gods have therefore decided that you aren't allowed to use this. Implicit conversion produces an rvalue and you can only bind a const reference to an rvalue.

Binding a rvalue to a const reference is still dangerous. You should not store a const reference for later use because it can become dangling.

Update: I noticed I never explained how calling a function taking a reference or assigning to a reference works. It's basically both the same thing.

A reference just gives something a(nother) name. There is no type change or casting or anything involved. So when you have

```
`func(val)`
```

then for the duration of the function the value in `val` has a second name `refVar`. Same with `int & refVal = val;`. There now is a second name for the value in val called `refVal`.

Afaik they are totally interchangeable.

Note: In a function call how it works is implementation detail but most compilers pass a `int *` to the function under the hood.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen What assembly? The compile fails and no assembly is generated.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen That's not an accident, that is on purpose so it has to do an implicit conversion. If the type is the same then no conversion happens and all is good.

Comment: Alright got it!. Upvoted your answer to apologize! Will delete my comments soon. And you should too.